# Want to connect two virtual machine (host windows) running on different laptops (using different networks)

Tags: vmware, hadoop

I want to build a hadoop cluster with one master node and 2 slave nodes. The master node will be running on a virtual box of pc-1. Slave nodes will be running on virtual box of pc-2. 
Slaves on same pc can reach one another but master can't. Need a solution of this problem.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: ubuntu 18.04. Host windows

Comment: It is not clear the problem is with Ubuntu. Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1231725/edit) your question and add details of your two networks and how they are connected, for example, details about bridge or NAT and any forwarding rules. We also need to know if `ufw` or another firewall app is running and if so, what rules you have set for the firewall.